# Admob Interstitial Opening a Few Times (Android)

Tags: java, android, admob

I am trying to add an Admob Interstitial to the application. I keep the screen horizontal, but the ad is popping up a few times. This is a very repulsive situation. How can I fix this? Thank you.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
private AdRequest adRequest;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxx");

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(){

                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } 

            }
    });

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

}}
```

Comment: You shouldn't load ad at runtime.

Comment: OK, but how do I show the ad when the app is open? Could you give me some more information? @HUSTLE

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6066980?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for help. I will do as you say. @HUSTLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify you can actually load ads at runtime but you shouldn't show the ads at runtime.

> For example you can show ads when the download is done then you can call the `mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()` method and show.

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxx");

mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded(){
          //The ad is ready call it when the timing is right
        }
});

mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```